# Convert wav to ogg vorbis in Python

Tags: python, mp3, ogg, transcoding, oggvorbis

How can I transcode a wav file to ogg vorbis format using Python?

I can convert to mp3 using PyMedia 1.3.7.3, but when I set the output stream type to 'ogg', I get the error: `oggvorbis_encode_init: init_encoder failed` and the script dies.

Comment: How can I make my question more clear for you, Ignacio?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From PyMedia's website:

> OGG( optional with vorbis library )

You need to install Vorbis in order for the OGG encoder to work. Since the old version of your question tells me that you're on windows you can grab it here:
http://www.vorbis.com/setup_windows/

Comment: Perhaps you can tell me which particular item I need to download and install. I followed the oggenc link to http://www.rarewares.org/ogg-libraries.php where the libvorbis.dll download looks promising. When I get the moment, I'll see if it makes a difference

Comment: I extracted the dll's in "ogg vorbis dlls using libVorbis v1.3.2" at http://www.rarewares.org/ogg-libraries.php#vorbislibs-libvorbis into my C:\WINDOWS\system32 directory, and ogg encoding worked.

Comment: The link is dead. Can someone kindly update it with an edit, please?